# Reference an inferred type in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, closures, typescript, inferred-type

Is there any way to reference an inferred type in TypeScript?

In the following example we get nice inferred types.

```
function Test() {
    return {hello:"world"}
}

var test = Test()
test.hello // works
test.bob   // 'bob' doesn't exist on inferred type
```

But what if I want to define a function that takes a parameter of the type: "Whatever `Test` returns", without explicitly defining the interface?

```
function Thing(test:???) {
  test.hello // works
  test.bob   // I want this to fail
}
```

This is a workaround, but it gets hairy if Test has parameters of its own.

```
function Thing(test = Test()) {} // thanks default parameter!
```

Is there some way to reference the inferred type  of whatever Test returns? So I can type something as "Whatever Test returns", without making an interface?

The reason I care is because I usually use a closure/module pattern instead of classes. Typescript already lets you type something as a class, even though you can make an interface that describes that class. I want to type something as whatever a function returns instead of a class. See [Closures in Typescript (Dependency Injection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314241/closures-in-typescript-dependency-injection) for more information on why.

The BEST way to solve this is if TypeScript added the abilty to define modules that take their dependencies as parameters, or to define a module inside a closure. Then I could just use the spiffy `export` syntax. Anyone know if there are any plans for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the body of an interface as a type literal:

```
function Thing(test: { hello: string; }) {
    test.hello // works
    test.bob   // I want this to fail
}
```

is equivalent to

```
interface ITest {
    hello: string;
}

function Thing(test: ITest) {
    test.hello // works
    test.bob   // I want this to fail
}
```

Just don't forget the `;` at the end of each member.

---

There is no syntax for naming or referring to inferred types. The closest you can get is using interfaces or type-literals for the members you are going to use. Interfaces and type-literals will match whatever type which at least has the defined members. "Duck-typing"

Comment: The main thing I want is to type `test` as "Whatever `Test` returns", and not to have to define the type

Comment: You can't, hence term "anonymous type" - it can't be named (technically when you type out a type literal, you are typing out a new anonymous type that has the same shape as the other anonymous type).

Answer (score 6):

It's now possible:

```js
function Test() {
    return { hello: "world" }
}

function Thing(test: ReturnType<typeof Test>) {
  test.hello // works
  test.bob   // fails
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types